# Additional Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Before I state my question, I would just like to say that I am fairly new to Android Studio and Java. I've just been learning as I go along and learning from my mistakes. So go easy on me, I am a newbie :P

So I've started a project in Android Studio. On my Main Activity I have created two buttons - 'Sign up' and 'Sign in'

Now I have successfully created and intent for my 'Sign up' button to go to a new activity (2nd activity)

but the problem is my 'Sign in' button. Why is it that when I click the 'Sign in' button it does not respond and go straight to another new activity (3rd activity), as I have created the onClickListener?

I have to click the 'Sign up' button which goes to the Sign up activity and then press 'back' AND THEN it allows me to click the Sign in button to go to the Sign in activity.

I really hope that makes sense.

I would be much appreciated if someone got back to me on that. It's probably a really simple fix, but as I said, I am a newbie *shoulder shrug*

However, for now I'll just tinker around and try to work it out

Thanks in advance!

(Let me know if you want me to post the relevant code).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static Button Button_sbm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

public void OnClickButtonListener(){
    Button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbut);
    Button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.Signupactivity");
                    startActivity(intent);


                    Button signinbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinbut);
                    signinbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent ("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.SignIn");
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Posting the code is standard.

Comment: My apologies. The code has been put above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are only linking the click listener for sign in after you click the sign up, before that, the button doesn't have a click listener.

Your code should be like this

```
public void OnClickButtonListener(){
Button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbut);
Button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.Signupactivity");
                startActivity(intent);
               }
            });
Button signinbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinbut);
signinbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent ("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.SignIn");
                        startActivity(intent);
                     }
});
```

Comment: Hmm that's weird. I put in what you gave me, but .'signinbut.setOnClickListener' (setOnClickListener) turns RED??

Thank you for responding

Comment: Sorry to pester you, but where did you forget to put the two closing brackets? :/

Comment: I think  I have got it figured out now.

Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also pretty new to Android coding but ran into a similar issue, the way I got round it was doing this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Button Button_sbm, signinbut;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbut);
        signinbut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinbut);

        Button_sbm.setOnClickListener(this);
        signinbut.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.signupbut:
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.Signupactivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.signinbut:
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.teamsix.fezzy.gosheesh.SignIn");
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also find that it makes it easier read/edit the code later.